# ng-click within ionic tag not working without interpolation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to pass a value to the function on ng-click, it is working outside ionic tag without interpolation but why do I need to interpolate it withing ionic tag. I am not getting it, sample code as follows:

```
<span ng-click="menuRouting(appCrtlVM.routingValue.home)"> {{appCrtlVM.routingValue.home}}</span>
```

Above is working without interpolation.

```
<ion-item menu-close  class="menuList padding-5" ng-click ="menuRouting({{appCrtlVM.routingValue.home}})">
     <div class="menu-img"><img src="./img/icons/home_icon1.png"></div><div class="menu-name"> Home </div>
</ion-item>
```

Above is not working without interpolation, it is being treated as plain text.

I will appreciate any of your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass expression to a function using ng-click, correct way to do is,

```
ng-click="menuRouting(appCrtlVM.routingValue.home)"
```

Also you can access the variable from the function,

```
$scope.menuRouting = function()
{
   //use the variable here
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly, and that is my question. If you will go through my question I mentioned it, the way you are telling is working outside IONIC tag but it is not working within IONIC. I want to know why is it happening? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.